# Why does preventDefault not get attched whith the default event argument?

Tags: javascript

It is said that if we use an event listener as:

```
document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click". function(/* event */){...});
```

then we don't need to mention `event` parameter inside the function's paranthesis. But if that is true then why don't the following work:

```
 document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click". function(/* event */){ event.preventDefault()});
```

Comment: Where did you hear that? Could you provide the resource that states this?

Comment: *"It is said that "* - who said that? Can you point to any official documentation?

Comment: Wait I am finding that post where I read that. Some posts say IE allows window.event to accessed without passing `event`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. It can't be implemented like this **officially** as long as `event` is not a reserved keyword.

Because people can then do:

```
document.getElementById("mybtn")
.addEventListener("click",function(troll,event) { 
  event.preventDefault(); // Boom! error.
});
```

and complain event is not working. Then it'll become necessary to document how people should **not** use the `event` object.

Some browsers might have a global event object. But implementations vary and it's not advisable to rely on such things.

Comment: You mean to say that the function would be confused about whether `troll` is the event or `event` is the event?

Comment: The first parameter will always be the event object. So in the above example `troll` is the actual event object and `event` is `undefined`. Even if some browsers expose a global event object, since you defined a `event` parameter, inside the event handler it'll refer to the local parameter than global one

Answer (score 1):

### History.

> " Some posts say IE allows window.event to accessed without passing event"

When Microsoft corporation reverse engineered JavaScript off Netscape Corporation without consultation, they chose not to implement passing `event` as a parameter to event handlers.

Instead, IE implemented a `window.event` property where data for individual events could be accessed. It was during the browser wars when convincing programmers to write code for your browser that failed in the opposition's browser was seen as a *good thing*. Since JavaScript is single threaded, no re-entrancy problems were created by IE's approach.

You may still see event handler code starting out as

```
function handler(event)
{   event = event || window.event;
    //  handler code    
}
```

which is a cross browser way of picking up IE's event object if not supplied to the handler function. At some point IE started passing the event object as a parameter in addition to setting it as a window property to maintain backwards compatibility in their browsers. It certainly works in IE 11 where

```
<span onclick="alert(arguments[0] === window.event);">click2</span>
```

alerts "true' when clicked, indicating `event` is passed as a parameter. In Firefox it is false on the basis `window.event` doesn't exist.

For current browsers name the first parameter of an event hander as `event`. If you want to support old versions of IE, use the cross browser code above. Never use 'window.event' by itself.

---

P.S.  Experimenting with document emulation mode in IE11, IE versions <= 8 do not pass event parameter objects to handlers. According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039060/ie9-quirks-mode-doesnt-pass-event-parameter-to-event-handler) neither does IE9 in quirks mode. Although IE8 may be the last operable version of IE under Windows XP, the browser is not supported by major commercial web sites in my country (Australia) which forces XP users to upgrade to a different browser. Whatever your case, do not use windows.event by itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click", function(event){ event.preventDefault()});
```

You are passing a callback function to the addEventListener. This function takes a parameter and you're using it.

Maybe changing it to another name and improving the indentation will help you understand this better.

```
document.getElementById("mybtn")
.addEventListener("click",
function(hello) { 
    hello.preventDefault()
});
```

To understand callback functions, try [this](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want use event directly then you have to pass event in that function from where you are calling that function. Otherwise you can create event like this:

```
document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click". function(/* event */){
 var e=document.getElementById("mybtn");
 e.preventDefault()
});
```